# Count the number of characters in a string and delete the duplicates

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm trying to find the number a each characters in a string. I'm using the below code.
I'm looping through each character. Now how do i modify the code so that I wont loop through the same character again. Ex: 'a' is appearing three times. I just want my code to consider only once.

```
        string input = "aajykumkar";
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
          
            count = input.Count(x => x == input[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of occurances of " + input[i] + " " + count);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: so basically you want to know whether a character is present or not in a string?

Comment: in the simplest case, use a list to keep a record of all the characters you've already seen, and don't run the count again if the current character appears in that list.

Comment: @LaurentS. I want to know how many times each character has been appeared in the string.

Comment: @ADyson not sure how to do it. Can you give me some hints on code?

Comment: @Ajay a neater answer has been posted already, but I'm puzzled by the "not sure" . Where are you stuck? Are you saying you don't know a) how to create a list, b) how to put things in it, and/or c) how to check whether a value exists in a list, or d) something else? Certainly a b and c should not be tricky, and can be researched quite easily.

Comment: @ADyson Got answer below! Thank you very much.

Comment: I know you did. My last comment was just challenging you to think through the process I described, because I think it's not as difficult as you perhaps imagined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it very easily using `System.Linq` namespace :

```
string input = "aajykumkar";
    
var groupedLetters = input.GroupBy(letter => letter);
    
foreach(var letter in groupedLetters)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number of occurances of " + letter.Key + " " + letter .Count());
}
```

Output:

```
Number of occurances of a 3
Number of occurances of j 1
Number of occurances of y 1
Number of occurances of k 2
Number of occurances of u 1
Number of occurances of m 1
Number of occurances of r 1
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;` in your code for it.

You can check the [working DEMO Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9l8l2j) at following :

https://dotnetfiddle.net/9l8l2j

Comment: Is is possible to return the string back, I'm looking for the output "a3j1y1k2u1m1r1"

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is very inefficient, because you're searching the string as many times as the string is long, ie the complexity of your algorithm is `O(n^2)`.

What you want is to parse the string once and keep track of how many times you encountered each element, then display that:

```
const string s = "oijewoijioajsdioajdiowrw";
foreach (var kvp in s.GroupBy(ch => ch).ToDictionary(w => w.Key, w => w.Count()))
    Console.WriteLine($"Number of occurances in {kvp.Key} is {kvp.Value}");
```

Comment: Is is possible to return the string back, I'm looking for the output "a3j1y1k2u1m1r1"

Comment: You mean something like `string.Concat(s.GroupBy(ch => ch).Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}{kvp.Count()}"))` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

### [See here for more information of looping through an array:](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/unique-array-items-in-c-sharp)

^ Also, it goes a bit further in, in how the linq method works from the answer of Ehsan Sajjad.

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            string input = "aajykumkar";;  
            int n = input.Length;  
  
            Console.WriteLine("Unique array elements: ");  
  
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
            {  
                bool isDuplicate = false;  
                for(int j=0;j<i;j++)  
                {  
                    if(items[i] == items[j])  
                    {  
                        isDuplicate = true;  
                        break;  
                    }  
                }  
  
                if(!isDuplicate)  
                {  
                    Console.WriteLine(items[i]);  
                      
                }  
            }  
  
            Console.ReadLine();  
        }
```

This gives an result of unique characters. Then you can also put a count on it, or make a new var outside of the loop, where you add everytime +=1 if you encounter a new (unique) char in the string

Comment: Is is possible to return the string back, I'm looking for the output "a3j1y1k2u1m1r1"